# Which kind of code is considered exception safe?

Tags: c++, exception, pthreads, mutex

A code which handles the exceptions well is called an exception safe code? Is this correct?

From here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/9759/11619

> You use lock/unlock pairs for the mutex. This is not exception safe.
>   So I would create an object that will do the lock in the constructor
>   and unlock in the destructor then use this to lock your mutexs. This
>   will make your code more exception safe.

```
class MutexLocker
{
    pthread_mutex_t&  mutex;
    MutextLocker(pthread_mutex_t& mutex)
        : mutex(mutex)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    }
    ~MutexLocker()
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
};
```

In which way is the above shown code exception safe? I don't see any exception handling over there.

Or does exception safe code mean where we can "add" the exception handling? So, the above shown code can be made exception safe by adding exception handling, but it isn't now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Exception safe" is a fairly overloaded term, but I would use it to describe sections of code which can have exceptions thrown through them and still maintain certain invariants (such as - nothing changes, no resources are leaked, all objects keep a valid state).

As an example, your `void * printHello (void* threadId)` function is correct (in that it always matches `pthread_mutex_lock (&demoMutex)` with `pthread_mutex_unlock (&demoMutex)`), but if someone changed the section in the middle so that it could throw an exception (for example, by setting the throw flags on `std::cout`), then your code would then permanently lock `demoMutex`, with no hope for it ever being released. This would constitute a bug in your program. `void * printHello (void* threadId)` is said to be "exception unsafe" because of this way in which bugs can easily be introduced into your program by adding exception handling to seemingly unrelated parts.

Using a RAII class to manage resources a good way to go about writing exception safe code (and is *the* resource management style to use in C++), because it avoids the need for duplicate manual cleanup in `catch(...)` blocks, and it enforces the cleanup of resources by using the type system.

Answer (score 8):

Exception Safety is not about handling exceptions, it is about guaranteeing a number of properties about the program even in the presence of exceptions.

You can usually speak about the [exception safety level](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExceptionGuarantee) of a given method:

- No Guarantee: this method is exception unsafe, that is no guarantee is made, at all.
- *Basic Exception Guarantee*: in case of exception no resource is leaked and the classes involved are still usable (but their state is unspecified), that is no memory leak, no file handle leak, no mutex leak and the invariants of the instances involved are still verified.
- *Strong Exception Guarantee*: in case of exception, all state is reversed to what it was prior to beginning. This is a transaction like semantic.
- *NoThrow Guarantee*: this method does not throw, it always succeeds.

In general, the *NoThrow Guarantee* only applies to the simplest methods (ie `.size()` on a `vector` for example) and the *Strong Exception Guarantee* may be costly to implement (being able to revert the effect or operating on a copy of the state may not be cheap).

On the other hand, the *Basic Exception Guarantee* is just that: **Basic**. Without it, safely operating a program is just impossible, so this is the **least** guarantee that is acceptable. If you leak resources or leave classes in an unusable state, the program may not be able to operate further.

This is why there is such an emphasis on RAII whenever exceptions are mentionned. Because RAII guarantees automatic cleanup of resources (memory, mutexes, files) whatever the path execution (regular return or exception) it is particularly desirable. However, RAII itself is not sufficient.

Related: Herb Sutter's GotW entry about [Exception Safety and Exception Specifications](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/082.htm).

Comment: I would call the "No Exception Guarantee" the "nothrow guarantee", to avoid any confusion with "No Guarantee" at all. And I would say that in the case of the basic guarantee, the objects are left in a "valid but otherwise unspecified state" - that is to say class invariants are maintained as you say, but stress that the value of the object after the exception is thrown could be *anything*. Then "usable" is a matter of what the objects are used for -- they can be destroyed, but other than that they might not be very use *ful*.

Comment: _No Guarantee_ is a fairly dubious guarantee class. It is only really a relevant concept for library code which calls back into user code and as such it could be better expressed as a requirement that the user code must not throw. If a function has `No Guarantee` and it is itself responsible for throwing an exception, then the function would would be better classed as simply being buggy.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I renamed the *No Exception Guarantee* and addressed the unspecified issue. I still don't have a proper explanation of *usable*, it is equivalent to the `std::move` guarantee (on its argument) but I don't see a concise way to express what can and cannot be done with the object.

Comment: @Mankarse: *No Guarantee* is a garbage tag to put everything that does not at least offers the *Basic Guarantee*. Any method such qualified should is potential buggy, but the bug may just not manifest itself for other reasons (ie, the parameters that are passed are such it always works as expected). I removed the italic to make it clearer.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: I edited the answer with some references. First, the classification presented here was introduced by David Abrahams in STL Port and further refined by various experts (among which Herb Sutter). Second, I added in a discussion about exception safety and why it is important (it also discusses why exception specification is not, though this is off-topic here).

Comment: Also, Sutter's article "GotW #102: Exception-Safe Function Calls" at http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/ shows how exception-unsafe code can be rather non-obvious (reinforcing that you should leverage RAII techniques whenever possible).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: ah yes, the new serie. Unfortunately it's yet another level I think because even `f(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T()), std::unique_ptr<T>(new T()))` is unsafe :x

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.10 This says that the destructor won't get called if the constructor fails, so does this means that even with constructor-destructor pair still the code isn't exception safe?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: it depends how exception safe the constructor is, to begin with. The constructor itself should not leak resources, even in the face of exceptions. Furthermore, do not forget that writing a destructor usually imply that you will need a copy constructor and assignment operator. In practice, you need to reuse proper RAII classes (smart pointers, etc..) and initialize them with the freshly acquired resources as soon as you got those, and then you should be fine, baring edge cases.

Comment: Mat you have been helpful, can you now tell me what concepts of mine (pertaining to C++) should be crystal clear before I can dare to understand throughly the RAII?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: RAII is based on scope and the lifetime of objects, so an obvious prerequisite is to really well understand scope and lifetime (in particular constructors and destructors). As for exceptions, this is something that comes up with experience and reading. If you are interested in learning more, and dust off the corners of C++, do read the Guru of the Week website (GotW). It might be somewhat hard to read.

Comment: how do you read that website? you are subscribed to its blogs RSS feed? Example: http://herbsutter.com/2012/01/20/gotw-103-smart-pointers-part-1-difficulty-310/ Some people have posted comments but where is the actual blog on smart pointers?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: the original site is http://www.gotw.ca/ and you can access the individual articles by number like http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/082.htm I can't find the list off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3):

the MutexLocker destructor is always called, also when an exception was raised in the block where it was constructed.

that is what makes a construct using your MutexLocker exception safe.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to *handle* an exception to be exception safe. You just have to survive when an exception is thrown.

The MutexLocker helps you do this by unlocking the mutex when you leave the scope. It doesn't matter if you leave by a return statement or because an exception is thrown.

Comment: helpful for sure, thanks. So, this means that the destructor is called when the exception is thrown?

Comment: It means that if you create a MutexLocker in your function, the destructor will be called when you leave the function. It doesn't matter *how* you leave the function.

Comment: parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.10 This says that the destructor won't get called if the constructor fails, so does this means that even with constructor-destructor pair still the code isn't exception safe? –

Comment: That's because if the constructor fails, there is no object to destroy. Nothing was constructed. In your case that would be if `pthread_mutex_lock` would throw an exception. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

> A code which handles the exceptions well is called an exception safe code?

Yes, but you do not say what well is. [This](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html) is a good read on exception safety.

> In which way is the above shown code exception safe?

That code is not exception safe in itself. That is meant to be used in a exception safe code. For example :

```
void bar()
{
  throw std::runtime_error( "lala" );
}

void foo()
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  bar();

  // OPS! mutex not unlocked
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

This problem is solved by using the class that automatically unlock the exception. Next example has exception handling with strong guarantees :

```
void foo()
{
  MutexLocker locker( mutex );

  try {
    bar();
  } catch ( const std::runtime_error & )
  {
    // revert changes
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided serves the purpose well. Simply because when execution leaves the block in which the `MutexLocker` object is defined, the object is destroyed and the mutex is released as per its destructor. This holds no matter the reason for the exit.

You don't have to code this class yourself though. The C++ standard specifies a class named `lock_guard` that does exactly that.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard